# Полетела virtualbox

Tags: linux, virtualbox

Видимо из-за последнего обновления полетела virtualbox, при этом переустановка пакетов не помогла, после чего я их просто удалил, надеясь установить заново. Но, оказалось, что не все нужные пакеты я могу установить. Например пакет `virtualbox-source` я не могу сново установить, так как пишет, что для этого нужно сначала "исправить ошибки в пакетах". Не подскажете в чем дело? Это пакеты не совместимы с последней версией ядра или дело в каких-то файлах настройки? (вроде я использовал полное удаление пакетов)
Заранее спасибо

Comment: попробуйте apt-get install -f иначе покажите полный стек ошибки

Comment: вот скрин. попробовал установить с использованием опции -f - ничего не получилось. пакеты с ошибками так и остались. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vUFS13h0KVEXN1fWRNnfEMdWOni2_zpF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: еще при попытке удалить установленные пакеты virtualbox вылазит вот такое сообщение: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15HrbPcvc43RkggfTfWm5hXBnZN-maOAD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: при этом только в первый раз - во второй все удаляется

Comment: не смогу помочь, может другие подскажут.

Comment: ясн, но все равно спасибо

Comment: Можно поподробнее какие ошибки? или попробуйте полностью удалить старый VirtualBox, пофиксить ошибки (apt-get install -f) и установить с пакета полученного с оф. сайта https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads (или по инструкции на этой же странице)

Comment: А откуда взят виртуалбокс? через официальную репу оракла?

Comment: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads тут есть и пакеты, и инструкция как добавить репозиторий virtualBox-а

Comment: Все это пробовал: ничего из этого не помогло. Но решение нашел: скачал инсталятор с официального сайта и установил - через репозиторий, почему-то, это сделать невозможно. Пишет что-то вроде: не все пакеты доступны. Теперь виртуал бокс работает, но дополнительные пакеты все равно установить нельзя. Все так же с ошибками. Это не очень мне нравится.